# Cannot implicity return type void in generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, events, delegates, console-application

I'm trying to build a simple generic class which should take an object and a delegate as generic parameters.I receive the following error when I bind a method to a event:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'ConsoleApp3.test.Del'

I do not understand why I receive this error as my delegate returns void and the method attached to the event also returns void.

This is the code:

```
interface ITerminable
    {
        int Param_1 { get; set; }
    }

    class test<T,F> where T:ITerminable,new() 
                    where F : Delegate,new()
    { 

        internal delegate void Del();
        internal static event Del Ev_fire;

        static T a = new T();
        static F b = new F();


        public static void InvokeEvent()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value not added !");

        }

        public static void Validate()
        {
            if (a.Param_1 < 0.5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Value Added");
                b.DynamicInvoke();
            }
            else
            {
                Ev_fire += InvokeEvent();

                Ev_fire?.Invoke();
            }
        }

    }
```

The error is at line : `Ev_fire += InvokeEvent();`

Comment: You should remove braces, like `Ev_fire += InvokeEvent;` instead of `Ev_fire += InvokeEvent();`

Comment: Have a look at [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/) for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: `Ev_fire += InvokeEvent;`

Comment: I did not see it sorry.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, what is the point of your comment under the answer?

Comment: @Sinatr the point is that there is nothing to answer, it's just a typo with braces, as I pointed in comment above